# Error in dependencies for xchat IRC client

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies

I was trying to install xchat IRC client, but I got the unmet dependencies error, saying it depends on `libsexy2` package. So, I installed the .deb file of the package online and when I open it, it says it depends on another which I already have here. It is up to date, how to get done with this?

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
xchat : Depends: libsexy2 (>= 0.1.8) but it is not installable
Recommends: xchat-indicator but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 1):

Since **XChat IRC** is discontinued ([the latest version of Ubuntu it support is 14.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xchat)), I'd suggest using another IRC software.

For example you can install [xchat-gnome](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xchat-gnome) ([official site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/XChat-GNOME)).

You can install it using:

- Via Synaptic Package Manager
- Via apt-get, using:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install xchat-gnome
  ```

Comment: Note that apps.ubuntu.com is not very update, the package is also available for 14.04: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xchat

Comment: @muru - thanks for the comment, I've updated my answer

Comment: It still doesn't work. I am getting the exact same error. 
Also, I am using Ubuntu 14.04, Xchat should work here, no? 
I am new to Ubuntu  and want to get to IRC to get to know more about coding and open source